# How can I perform transactions in typeorm 0.2 version with NestJS

Tags: mysql, transactions, nestjs, typeorm

I used mysql, and in the local environment, the logs rolled back normally, but my table has all the data. (a, b, c table)

in my code, entity create (a, b, c entity) and save with queryRunner.manager

I set cEntity to underdefined for transaction error testing.

```
"statusCode": 400,
"timestamp": "2023-12-18T15:45:00.000Z",
"path": "/api/v1/rsvcenter/inquiry/hall",
"message": "Cannot save, given value must be an entity, instead \"undefined\" is given.",
```

but, that error occurred

```
QueryRunnerAlreadyReleasedError: Query runner already released.
 Cannot run queries anymore.
```

How can I modify my code to make transactions work normally

version
typeorm 0.2.33
nest 7.5.1

```
async testTransaction(user: User, dto: Dto): Promise<boolean> {
        const queryRunner = await getConnection().createQueryRunner();

        try {
            await queryRunner.startTransaction();
            const manager = queryRunner.manager;

            const aEntity = this.utils.createEntity(dto, user);
            const save1 = await manager.save(aEntity);

            const no1 = save1.no;
            const bEntity = await this.utils2.createEntity(dto, no1);
            const cEntity = await this.utils3.createEntity(dto, no1);

            await manager.save(bEntity);
            await manager.save(cEntity);
            await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
            return true;
        }
        catch (error) {
            await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
            throw new BadRequestException(error, "transaction failed");
        }
        finally {
            await queryRunner.release();
        }
}
```

Independent tests were conducted in the same environment.

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Connection } from "typeorm";
import { UserEntity } from "./entity/user.entity";
import { PGEntity } from "./entity/pg.entity";

@Injectable()
export class TransactionService {

    constructor( private connection: Connection ) { }

    async testTransaction() {
        const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();

        await queryRunner.startTransaction();

        try {
            // const user = new UserEntity();
            const user = queryRunner.manager.getRepository(UserEntity).create();
            user.name = 'transaction test';
            const userData = await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(UserEntity).save(user);

            // const pg = new PGEntity();
            const pg = queryRunner.manager.getRepository(PGEntity).create();
            pg.userNo = userData.no;
            pg.price = 20000;

            
            await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(PGEntity).save(pg);

            throw new Error('zzz')
            await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
        }

        catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
        }

        finally {
            await queryRunner.release();
        }
    }
}
```

in my console maybe rollback is success but TABLE inserted data;;

```
query: set session character_set_connection=utf8
query: set session character_set_client=utf8
query: set session character_set_results=utf8
query: set collation_connection=utf8_general_ci
query: set names utf8
query: set session character_set_connection=utf8
query: set session character_set_client=utf8
query: set session character_set_results=utf8
query: set collation_connection=utf8_general_ci
query: set names utf8
query: START TRANSACTION
query: set session character_set_connection=utf8
query: set session character_set_client=utf8
query: set session character_set_results=utf8
query: set collation_connection=utf8_general_ci
query: set names utf8
query: INSERT INTO `center`.`test_user`(`no`, `name`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?) -- PARAMETERS: ["transaction test"]
query: set session character_set_connection=utf8
query: set session character_set_client=utf8
query: set session character_set_results=utf8
query: set collation_connection=utf8_general_ci
query: set names utf8
query: INSERT INTO `center`.`test_pg`(`no`, `user_no`, `price`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: [5,20000]
Error: zzz
    at TransactionService.testTransaction (/Users/diehreo/Desktop/dev/iwedding_node_api/dist/src/transaction/transaction.service.js:32:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async TransactionController.testTransaction (/Users/diehreo/Desktop/dev/iwedding_node_api/dist/src/transaction/transaction.controller.js:22:16)
query: ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Try adding
await queryRunner.connect();
after
const queryRunner = await getConnection().createQueryRunner();